# Why does my div shrink when overflow is set to 'visible' but expands when the div is set to overflow or auto?

Tags: html, css

I've had an issue with this project where a div appeared to have a gap from the div above it. After debugging, I've found that the gap is not just on the top, but the bottom as well. When I added `overflow:auto` or `overflow:hidden`, the mysterious gap disappeard and the divs touch (as desired), but when I set `overflow:visible` or don't set it at all, there is about 40px taken off the top and bottom. Why is it doing this?

[Full JSFiddle for example](https://jsfiddle.net/g4m170mc/2/), just add `overflow:auto` to "hero-container" in the CSS to 'fix' it.

```css
#header{
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #05568D;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#header > ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    background-color:darkmagenta;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#header > ul > li{
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}

#hero{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}

#hero-container{
    margin: 0px 100px 0px 100px;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: visible;
}

body{
    background: #0769AD;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
}

.container{
    width: 96%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header" class="container">
       
       <ul>
           <li>Download</li>
           <li>API Documentation</li>
           <li>Blog</li>
           <li>Plugins</li>
           <li>Browser Support</li>
       </ul>
       
   </div>
   
   <div id="hero" class="container">
       
       <div id="hero-container">
           
           <p>This is a paragraph</p>
           
       </div>
   </div>
```

Can someone please explain this logic to me because I am baffled. What is the need for overflow if it's just a `<p>` and the height of its parents are even set?

Comment: you are facing a margin collapsing that you break by setting overflow:hidden [the default one is visible]

Answer (score 0):

Because `<p></p>` have the default margin top and bottom, if you set `*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}` you don't have this problem.

Comment: I wouldn't set it on the `*` though, but just limit it to the elements you want to remove the `margin` and `padding` from

Comment: It's also enough if you use `p{margin:0;}`